# Is acl entity role available in Api4 explorer?

Tags: apiv4

I'm pretty sure the acl_entity_role entity is supported by CiviCRM APIv4. Why doesn't it appear in the entity list on civicrm%2Fapi4#/explorer/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me on CiviCRM 5.46. Are you using an older version of CiviCRM?

[image: ACL Entity Role]

Comment: FWIW I think this was added in CiviCRM 5.39.

Comment: <forehead-slap>I didn't even think to check my version.</forehead-slap>
<thanks/>